# dynamically change images in an animation IOS

Tags: ios, animation

I have a requirement to animate images . I have a large number of images and this needs to be played as an video. In between playing sometimes i need to change some images as they will be updated at server. so playing should automatically update this new images .

I have tried using UIImageView. There we cannot control the animation.
I then tried CAKeyframeAnimation supplying image array to values property. I could play and pause the animation. But here also i cannot dynamically change the image while playing.

Can anyone help me in solving this problem.

Thanks
mia

Answer (score 0):

The animation system on UIImageView is very limited. I would suggest that you make your own implementation with say 2 image view.

You would than change the image in one imageview and the fade in and out using `UIView animateWithDuration`

I have written a method for you. Please note: I have not tested it.

It assumes you have your frames in a array called 'frames' and have two `UIIMageView` placed on top of each other called 'imgv1' and 'imgv2'

```
-(void)performAnimationOfFrameAtIndex:(NSNumber*)indexNum
{        
    int index = [indexNum intValue];
    if(index >= frames.count)
    {
        return;
    }
    UIImage *img = [frames objectAtIndex:index];

    UIImageView *imgIn;
    UIImageView *imgOut;
    if(index % 2 == 0)
    {
        imgIn = imgv1;
        imgOut = imgv2;
    }
    else {
        imgIn = imgv2;
        imgOut = imgv1;
    }
    imgIn.image = img;
    [self.view sendSubviewToBack:imgIn];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.1 animations:^{
        imgIn.alpha = 1;
        imgOut.alpha = 0;
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(performAnimationOfFrameAtIndex:) withObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:index+1] waitUntilDone:NO];
    }];

}
```

Comment: You mean if i have 100 frames .. i need to use 3 image views and place first 3  and then replace next 3 images in these image views and so on. could you please elaborate a  little ?

Answer (score 0):

Use two `UIImageViews` and swap them.

If you have a weak reference on the "animation" `UIView`, be sure to check if animation has finished in the completion block. Otherwise you may experience performance issues when you navigate to another view, recursive calls to animation method will continue!

```
- (void)animateImagesAtIndex:(NSNumber *)imageIdx {
    // Do something here
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1 animations:^{
        // Do swap
    }
    completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        if (finished) {
            [self animateImagesAtIndex:imageIdx];
        }
    }];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

UIImageView supports animations for a series of images. You only have to set the properties animationImages with an array of the images, and call the methods  startAnimating and stopAnimating.